# How does this implementation of AutoClosable work?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the following code snippet. I understand that `AutoClosable` interface defines a `close()` method.

```
  protected AutoCloseable fooAction() {
    enableFooResources();
    return () -> {
      disableFooResources()
    };
  }
```

What does the construct of `return () -> {}` mean? How does it return an AutoClosable object.

Appreciate if someone could point to the name of the language construct so that I can look this up.

Comment: you're looking at a lambda implementation of AutoCloseable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `() -> ...` syntax is called a lambda expression. They are basically an alternative to anonymous classes that has only one method (though they are not compiled into anonymous classes).

Your code is similar to:

```
  protected AutoCloseable fooAction() {
    enableFooResources();
    return new AutoCloseable() {
        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
            SurroundingClass.this.disableResources();
        }
    }
  }
```

The intention is likely to provide a way for the caller to close whatever resource `fooAction` is going to do.

Learn more about lambdas [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).